# How can I render/view/read imported excel files with multiple sheets on web page in Angular?

Tags: angular, excel

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-xlsheet',
  templateUrl: './xlsheet.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./xlsheet.component.css']
})
export class XlsheetComponent implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');   
  }
  data:[][] = new Array();
  onFileChange(evt: any){
    const target : DataTransfer =<DataTransfer>(evt.target);
    if (target.files.length !==1) throw new Error ('Can not use multiple files');   
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws:XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];
      // console.log(ws);
      this.data = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws,{header:1}));
          // console.log(this.data);
    };
    
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="header">Excel File Utility App</h2>
    <div class="choose-file">
        <input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple="false"> 
         <h2>Excel file content displayed below:</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content-area">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
                    <td *ngFor="let cell of row">
                        {{cell}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have done part of codes which can view just single page of excel file. But I want to view all sheets included in the file one after another. I am struggling to resolve the issue.

I have attached my code snippet. I want some one's held to give input on how to read/view the each sheet one after another in case of multiple sheets in one excel file